# cmake: How to include another project generated header

Tags: cmake, gflags

*gflags* had cmake-migration branch,
it will genrate header in `${buildir}/include`,
how can i include the genrated header?
Is there a `var` liked `gflags_generated_headers`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the entire directory with Include_directories command.

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${buildir}/include)

Then set the Generated property of the specific file to True.

set_source_files_properties(${buildir}/include/Myheader.h PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)